# ng-src not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

Main issue I am having, is i am using ng-src="" to add in images dynamically via my JSON file. I ran into the issue where inside the img element (within the html) where the ng-src="" is located it is not sourcing in the images I have stored at all.

And when I go to inspect the element I see both ng-src=location/some.png" and src="location/some.png" both inside the element within the DOM.

But when I just use src="" with out the directive the images appear but when I refresh the browser, the images disappears sometimes and reappear other times, acting very buggy.

Here I have a js fiddle of my situation and code below:
http://jsfiddle.net/coder101/c3X7B/4/

HTML:

```
 <div ng-app="indieApp">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div id="main" role="main" ng-controller="imageAddCrtl">
            <ul id="tiles" class="">
                <li ng-repeat="image in imageInfo">
                    <img ng-src="{{image.path}}" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.wrap .space {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:80px;
}
.wrap #tiles {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    /** Needed to ensure items are laid out relative to this container **/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/**
 * Grid items
 */
 .wrap #tiles li {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    display: none;
    /** Hide items initially to avoid a flicker effect **/
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px;
}
.wrap #tiles li.inactive {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.wrap #tiles li img {
    display: block;
}
```

JS (this is for an infinite scroll using the wookmark Library I have, not apart of the problem to my
knowledge)

```
(function ($) {

    var $tiles = $('#tiles'),
        $handler = $('li', $tiles),
        $main = $('#main'),
        $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document),
        options = {
            autoResize: true, // This will auto-update the layout when the browser window is resized.
            container: $main, // Optional, used for some extra CSS styling
            offset: 20, // Optional, the distance between grid items
            itemWidth: 210 // Optional, the width of a grid item
        };

    /**
     * Reinitializes the wookmark handler after all images have loaded
     */
    function applyLayout() {
        $tiles.imagesLoaded(function () {
            // Destroy the old handler
            if ($handler.wookmarkInstance) {
                $handler.wookmarkInstance.clear();
            }

            // Create a new layout handler.
            $handler = $('li', $tiles);
            $handler.wookmark(options);
        });
    }

    /**
     * When scrolled all the way to the bottom, add more tiles
     */
    function onScroll() {
        // Check if we're within 100 pixels of the bottom edge of the broser window.
        var winHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $window.height(), // iphone fix
            closeToBottom = ($window.scrollTop() + winHeight > $document.height() - 100);

        if (closeToBottom) {
   // Get the first then items from the grid, clone them, and add them to the bottom of the grid
            var $items = $('li', $tiles),
                $firstTen = $items.slice(0, 10);
            $tiles.append($firstTen.clone());

            applyLayout();
        }
    };

    // Call the layout function for the first time
    applyLayout();

    // Capture scroll event.
    $window.bind('scroll.wookmark', onScroll);
})(jQuery);
```

In the important external libraries I have attached:

imagesInfo.json -> is where the images are being sourced from my local server, as I have the images stored in a images directory

controller.js -> is where I have the angularJS information

angular.js -> well just the need angular lib

The rest of the libraries I have are just for the image functionally of the infinite scroll and setting up a grid styled layout

Comment: Your plunker is missing: difficult to help you.

Comment: I can see the plunker, it's missing ng-app="indieApp"... But once that's added it seems to work but it's hard to tell if it's having the same problem because the images don't exist.

Comment: I added more detail to the question! So you have a clearer picture as to what is going on

Answer (score 0):

### You forgot to add `ng-app="indieApp"`

plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LfMer1?p=preview